# Cant get access_token

Tags: javascript, node.js, access-token

I get my body with `access_token` but I want to use the only `access_token` from the body. But give me `access_token` is undefined

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(body.access_token);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Your question looks unclear and is difficult to understand the problem you are facing. Please add more details for people to be able to help you.

Also, to begin debugging, you could print out the contents of `body` and check its json.

Comment: ok I am making a post request to get my access_token and I get it from my body. I wrote console.log(body) and I see my access_token inside body object but When I write console.log(body.access_token) it gives me undefined

Comment: I just want to get my access_token from body object

Comment: and I will write to authorization: Bearer body.access_token

Comment: What does `body` look like?

Comment: {
  "access_token":"1231231313123312",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,  
}
like that

Comment: whats `console.log(typeof body)` show?

Comment: it says string I check it now

Comment: I am using  substring now

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons that could make this issue.

1. If your option doesn't have `json: true` like this:

   ```
   request({
       uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
   }, (error, response, body) => {
       if (error) throw new Error(error);
       console.log(typeof body)
       //string
   })
   ```

   So that you can put `json: true` to the option, body will be `ojbect`. The code will look like this:

   ```
   request({
       uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
       json: true
   }, (error, response, body) => {
       if (error) throw new Error(error);
       console.log(typeof body)
       //object
   })
   ```
2. If you set up `option` with `json: true` and the body still is a string. I think your API might response a wrong format. Like you commented above:

`{ "access_token":"1231231313123312", "token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600, }`
It may be due to the last comma which leads to couldn't parse your response to an object.